# ¿Como eliminar en una pilo o arraylist un dato y que las posiciones se muevan?

Tags: java, arraylist, pilas

La idea es en una pila o arraylist eliminar un dato que este en el medio y ese espacio que queda allí no quede nulo para que asi si se borran varios números no haya espacios nulos entre los datos del Array o pila.

Comment: Olvidaste poner tu codigo para que puedan darte sugerencias.

Comment: Porque no agregas tu código Juan?  te sugiero leer [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Usas el método `remove(int index)` del `ArrayList`, aca un ejemplo

```
ArrayList<String> letras = new ArrayList();
letras.add("a"); //index 0
letras.add("b"); //index 1
letras.add("c"); //index 2
letras.add("d"); //index 3

int index = 2;

letras.remove(index);
```

El nuevo arreglo quedaría

```
"a", "b", "d"
```

Donde la letra `"d"` ocupa el index `2`.

Answer (score -1):

En un ArrayList con el método `remove()` lo logras, ya en un Array es un poco mas completo. El método `remove()` recibe como parámetro la posición del ArrayList a eliminar. El método `remove()` elimina la posición.

```
ArrayList<String> frutas = new ArrayList<String>();

frutas.add("mango");
frutas.add("pera");
frutas.add("manzana");
frutas.add("uva");
// El ArrayList posee 4 posiciones 

frutas.remove(1); // posicion 2 eliminada (pera).

// El ArrayList ahora posee 3 posiciones.
```

Comment: Gracias. Pero otra pregunta, al utilizarlo en este caso ¿la posición de manzana seria ahora 1 o seguiría siendo 2?

Comment: Seria: mango (0), manzana (1), uva (2)

Comment: @JuanDVillamil la posición de manzana seria 1.

Comment: Una retroalimentación que acompañe el voto negativo tambien es bien recibida.